# Different Custom DNS for Each Wifi SSID

Tags: wireless-networking, router, dns, ip, ssid

I want to set Custom DNS for each SSID Wifi.

**For example,**

```
SSID 1 - Cloudflare DNS
SSID 2 - Adgaurd DNS
SSID 3 - Default
```

**I have ZTE Router**

[image]

Comment: Not possible with consumer grade products.